# How can I easily save dataGridView to .XLS or or .CSV without prompting user with saveFileDialog C# Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, datagridview

I am working on a project that will allow a user to view a MySQL database table in a C# Winform dataGridView.

I want the users to be able to save the dataGridView contents to c:\temp\export.xls without prompting the user with saveFileDialog (it is fine that it uses saveFileDialog, as long as it can bypass any user input and save as c:\temp\export.xls) with a button click.  I need help modifying the second part to bypass user input.

The code I am using to save the data is in two parts (The code in the second part prompts the user for save location, but i want to omit that and have it automatic):

```
    private void ToCsV(DataGridView dGV, string filename)
    {
        string stOutput = "";
        // Export titles:
        string sHeaders = "";

        for (int j = 0; j < dGV.Columns.Count; j++)
            sHeaders = sHeaders.ToString() + Convert.ToString(dGV.Columns[j].HeaderText) + "\t";
        stOutput += sHeaders + "\r\n";
        // Export data.
        for (int i = 0; i < dGV.RowCount - 1; i++)
        {
            string stLine = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < dGV.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
                stLine = stLine.ToString() + Convert.ToString(dGV.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value) + "\t";
            stOutput += stLine + "\r\n";
        }
        Encoding utf16 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1254);
        byte[] output = utf16.GetBytes(stOutput);
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
        bw.Write(output, 0, output.Length); //write the encoded file
        bw.Flush();
        bw.Close();
        fs.Close();
    }
```

2nd part:

```
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.Filter = "Excel Documents (*.xls)|*.xls";
        sfd.FileName = "export.xls";
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
          // ToCsV(dataGridView1, @"c:\temp\export.xls");   ???????
           ToCsV(dataGridView1, sfd.FileName); 
        }
```

I want to modify the second part to save automatically @ c:\temp\export.xls.   Hopefully i have explained my intentions well.  I have looked into the NPOI library but not sure if this is what i need.  It would be nice to do it in the background in case, for some reason, the user doesnt have excel installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just do this, or if you want to run this in the back ground you can view here how to use the background worker class, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //I would probabaly generate a time stamped Filename so not to over write existing files
   // You can use something like a background worker to run this in the back ground
   ToCsV(dataGridView1, @"c:\temp\export.xls");   
}
```

Comment: I want to overwrite the previous file, so that's not an issue, but thanks for the heads up.  I have tried this, but it still seems to prompt for save location/filename.  am i doing something wrong?

Comment: are you still using anything with the Save File Dialog, I am not seeing anything in your ToCsv Method that would prompt anyone for something.  Comment out anything regarding the SAveFileDialog.Make your button click method look just like mine.

Comment: i have a different button that does prompt the user for save location etc....but it is in a button click event.  not sure that those commands would be run by clicking an altogether seperate button.  do you think it could have compiled wrong and never updated possibly?

Comment: WOW.  im not sure what the deal was, but its working fine now using ToCsV(dataGridView1, @"c:\temp\export.xls");

Comment: Thanks dude!  i had tried that already, but it didnt work.  2nd time is a charm!  you da man! ;)